# How to open pdf file like wifi2.pdf by direct command in directory terminal as wifi2.pdf

Tags: pdf

I want to open my pdf files using Terminal but I donot want to use this "xdg-open" command every time. What is the solution. Thank You

Comment: The default pdf reader is evince. So just 'evince file.pdf'.

Comment: Can I write a command or change any thing so that I can avoid to write evince everytime

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean write a command to avoid writing 6 letters 'everytime'... In any event you can put an alias in your `~/.($SHELL)rc` as `alias e=evince` if you really want to save typing 5 letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write as less as possible when opening a pdf file, you should define an alias. In a file called ~/.bashrc you can define aliases like this:

```
alias pdf="evince "
```

Refresh the environment with

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

and then use the alias:

```
pdf file.pdf
```

Comment: Please explain this commands again. I am new in Ubuntu